# How to get rid of appsettings.json and sni.dll while publishing NativeAot app as a single file

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, native-aot

Publishing NativeAot app as a single file by the following command:
`dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64` is making appsettings.json and sni.dll as a separate dependency.

Basically I want to publish my NativeAot web-api as a single file in dotnet8.0. I want that it should generate only one single-file but it is generating appsettings.json file and sni.dll file along with the exe file.

The Publish options are as follows:

- Configuration: Release | Any CPU
- Target Framework: .net8.0
- Target-Runtime: win-x64
- NativeAot: true (enabled)

How to generate one single file containing values from appsettings and get rid of sni.dll in the NativeAot web-api application.

Comment: What if you try to embed appsettings.json in the Executable? Is the `sni.dll` a critical dependency for your application?

Comment: Currently I dont have the idea how to embad the appsettings.json in executable single file in my mind. And yes the sni.dll file is the critical dependency, I have tried by deleting this file and the application gives error like Native Dependency are not resolved, can not find sni.dll file(verbal explanation).